# Were slings used as melee weapons?

Tags: warfare, weapons

Slings were a common weapon in history. Cheap to construct and with ammo plentiful, they were very cost effective to field in great numbers.

**What I want to know is if there is any historical evidence for slings being used in melee.** (with a rock wedged in the cup and used like a flail or sap.)

Note that I'm not asking if there is evidence of them being *effective* in melee combat, merely if they were used as such. (Obviously, a knife or short sword would likely be better)

Comment: yes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sling_(weapon)#Combat

Comment: You should do a google search before asking a question

Comment: @Jeroenk Read that entire article already. Found no reference to use in melee. Can you quote the relevant text?

Comment: Check out the staff sling: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sling_(weapon)#Staff_sling

Comment: @DannyReagan then I retract my close vote.

Comment: Does mace count? Also Japanese used to have chains with heavy balls at the ends.

Answer (score 1):

Diodorus Siculus' chronicle of the Battle of Eknomos in 311BC:

> "But when Hamilcar saw that his men were being overpowered and that
>   the Greeks in constantly increasing number were making their way into
>   the camp, he brought up his slingers, who came from the Balearic
>   Islands and numbered at least a thousand. By hurling a shower of great
>   stones, they wounded many and even killed not a few of those who were
>   attacking, and they shattered the defensive armour of most of them.
>   For these men, who are accustomed to sling stones weighing a mina,
>   contributed a great deal toward victory in battle, as they practised
>   constantly with the sling since childhood. In this way they drove the
>   Greeks from the camp and defeated them. Their equipment for fighting
>   consists of three slings, and of these they keep one around the head,
>   another around the belly, and the third in the hands. In the business
>   of war they hurl much larger stones than do any other slingers, and
>   with such force that the missile seems to have been shot, as it were,
>   from a catapult; consequently, in their assaults upon walled cities,
>   they strike the defenders on the battlements and disable them, and in
>   pitched battles they crush both shields and helmets and every kind of
>   protective armour. And they are so accurate in their aim that in the
>   majority of cases they never miss the target before them. The reason
>   for this is the continual practice which they get from childhood, in
>   that their mothers compel them, while still young boys, to use the
>   sling continually; for there is set up before them as a target a piece
>   of bread fastened to a stake, and the novice is not permitted to eat
>   until he has hit the bread, whereupon he takes it from his mother with
>   her permission and devours it!!".

Comment: Nice reference, but it does not appear to answer the question. Can you highlight the relevant passage?

Comment: I asked specifically if they were used as *melee* weapons. I am well aware of their use in warfare as ranged weapons.

Comment: @DannyReagan Sorry English is my third language. My mistake. I doubt you'll find any references on that though, even a poor slinger could probably afford a knife and would generally run away.

Comment: Are there any heroic or mythical singers in ancient mythologies?

Comment: Have you heard of David versus Goliath?

Comment: @DannyReagan: King David brought down Goliath with a sling. I'll let you decide whether to classify David as "heroic" or "mythological."

Comment: I have heard of David and Goliath. Unfortunately, it provides no clarity on alternative uses of slings as David uses it as intended.